# Nested `mdframed` environments and footnotes

Tags: margins, footnotes, mdframed, nesting

Suppose that you have two `mdframed` environments, one nested inside the other, and a footnote in the first `mdframed` environment but *not* in the second.  See the MWE example below.

[image: With footnote]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
Test frame\footnote{Test footnote}
\begin{mdframed}
Test nested frame
\end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

And here is what the same example looks like without the `\footnote` command.

[image: Without footnote]

There are (at least) two problems here.  The first of course is that, with the footnote, the nested `mdframed` environment is too large and goes outside the right margin.  The second problem is that, as the footnote appears in the *first* `mdframed` environment, it should be appearing at the end of the *first* `mdframed` environment, not the second.  I suspect these problems are related (it's probably worth noting that if you move the `footnote` command into the second `mdframed` environment, everything is the correct size).

Any idea what's going on here or how to fix it?

Comment: For the footnotes, `footnote` package could help you; maybe writing your code into `savebox` environment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,colback=white]
Test frame\footnote{Test footnote}
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,colback=white]
Test nested frame
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but un-fortunately I need to be able to have un-break-able boxes inside un-break-able boxes =/

Comment: @JonathanGleason  So what? Although `tcolorbox` can made breakable boxes, by default those like of my MWE are  unbreakable.